# What is Websphere?

Tags: java, websphere

**Googling this question returns lots of results with marketing jargon.**

What I am looking for is a summary of what it does, more along these lines [What is Maven?](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html)

[This is the closest I could get.](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/definition/WebSphere)

Comment: WebSphere is an application server [more](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/in/websphere/)

Comment: +1 I can't find a clear explanation either. More IBM propaganda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"WebSphere" in the most abstract sense is a [brand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere) encompassing various products, so "a brand" is about as good an answer as you can get.

What one usually refers to when saying "WebSphere", though, is the [WebSphere Application Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server), which (as the name implies) is an application server - something that runs EJBs and other server-side Java technologies like servlets, JMS, etc. An example of another important player in this space is [JBoss AS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss_Application_Server).

Finally, another possible definition of "WebSphere" is ["its creator's biggest technology mistake"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-11944966) ;)

Comment: +1. And thanks for the last link, I always suspected something like that.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, yeah, I've heard that's a common feeling among people subjected to WAS :)

Answer (score 4):

Unlike a regular web server which simply provides clients acces to html-documents, which their browser then displays as websites, an application server allows for programms/scripts to be invoked by requesting websites, which dynamically generate the websites.

In this case the scripts are written in Java. This allows for a lot of the apis provieded in Java to be utilised by your web-application (the website itself is simply the frontend of your webapplication)

So web sphere is an application server from IBM. Simple as that.  [This](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/definition/WebSphere) tells you what it can do.

Hope that helps.

Comment: " an application server allows for programms/scripts to be invoked by requesting websites, which dynamically generate the websites" so it's like CGI?

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere is an application server which supports a lot of advanced functions including load balancing, database connection managing, advanced logging options and many more.

On the other hand it introduces severe overhead, is difficult to administrate and one has to learn a lot to use it effectively. And more often than on other servers you find yourself in [JAR hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell). Been there.